# Python pandas dataseries slice with label vs index discrepancy

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

```
s2 = pd.Series([10,20,30,40,50,60], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

When I select slice using the labels as below

```
print(s2['b':'e'])
```

output is

```
b    23
c    33
d    43
e    54
dtype: int64
```

but when I select slice using index as below

```
print(s2[1:4])
```

output is

```
b    23
c    33
d    43
dtype: int64
```

Why is that when we select with index, it is selecting with step-1 whereas with label it is selecting the final label as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html): "A slice object with labels 'a':'f' (Note that contrary to usual Python slices, both the start and the stop are included, when present in the index! See Slicing with labels and Endpoints are inclusive.)"

When you have an index that isn't the default `RangeIndex` (such as the strings in your example), slicing includes the start and stop. For a RangeIndex (or when specifying indices) slicing includes `start` to `stop-1`.

Comment: Thanks, was watching video tutorials on pandas. Google search did not lead to pandas documentation. Marked as answer

Answer (score 1):

```
s2['b':'e']
```

this works similar to `df.loc[]`

here a slice object with labels 'a':'f' (Note that contrary to usual Python slices, both the start and the stop are included, when present in the index! See Slicing with labels and Endpoints are inclusive.)

where as `s2[1:4]`

this works simlar to `df.iloc[]`

here general slicing rules of python apply.
refer this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html